# How to detect a c++ program on an unknow computer on the local network from an Android device

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets

I have a program that is in C++ on a computer. I also have a Android app (Android version > 4.0). Both are communicating via TCP socket. The C++ program is the Server Socket, and the android app is the Client Socket.

Now, this works well if I tell my Android app what is the port and IP of the C++ server. I would like to be able to discover my C++ program from the Android device. After some research, I found that I could broadcast a message on the network from the C++ program that contains the IP and Port of the computer. Then my android program will listen to the broadcasting address until it listens to the server's broadcasting message.

I don't know how to do that in C++... Is is a good idea? If yes how can I do that? If not, what would be the better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: broadcasting is a good idea, but the broadcast will not include the port! is it send to a specific port and your android device listens to it

Comment: a broadcast is send like a normal tcp package, you can get the broadcast adress very easy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

Comment: @PhilippSander : no I would like to also detect the port... so I can avoid conflict... Is there another way to do that?

Comment: as far as i understood tcp and broadcast: no. sorry

Comment: why dont you just always use 1 port for broadcasting and 1 port for the "real" data

Comment: The port that I'll use to brodcast could be in conflict too. So I won't be able to listen to that port on my client I will not be able to because another program will already be using it... right?

Comment: could yes.... but the chance are pretty low

Comment: Let the server use UTP to broadcast its ip and TCP port.

Comment: Your android client could also try to connect with all the ip addresses in the subnet. If all is dhcp the server ip will not differ too much from the client`s own ip.

Comment: @greenapps : you mean UDP right ? UDP needs to send messages to a port I guess... so it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes UDP. Please read question nr 1204396.

Answer (score 0):

Getting client-server stuff working reliably can be quite challenging; there always seems to be one more edge-case that needs to be resolved. Rather than rebuilding the wheel, I recommend just using an existing library where someone else has already worked out all the kinks. I haven't used it yet, but the [AllJoyn open-source project](https://allseenalliance.org/developer-resources/alljoyn-open-source-project) looks very promising.

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I need, but it seems that AllJoyn has to be installed as a service before installing our app... I'll take a look closer about it...